# ContinueWhenAll doesn't wait for all task to complete

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task

I have found a piece of code on the web and have modified it a bit to see how it works, but now I have a problem with `ContinueWhenAll` as it doesn't wait for all tasks to be finished:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    int j = i;
    var compute = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => results.Add(DoSomething(j)));
    tasks.Add(compute);
}
```

I'm using this code to add all task to list. `DoSomething` function computes some results and adds them to `BlockingCollection`. I have another display function which writes all added results from `BlockingCollection` to the console.

I have used this code to wait for all tasks to complete, but it looks like it doesn't wait for them as the program displays the standard `"Press any key to continue"` message just a few milliseconds after it was started. (It should take ~20 sec for program to complete)

```
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(), result => results.CompleteAdding());
```

However if I add `Task.WaitAll(consume)` to end of the program, program works fine:

```
var consume = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => display(results));
//results = BlockingCollection that I mentioned
```

As far as I understand, the program will not have enough time to display all result from `BlockingCollection` but still it has more than enough time to display some while waiting for all tasks to complete.

Could someone explain me why Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll doesn't wait for all results to be computed and program comes to an end just like there is no that line of code in program (after few milliseconds)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll` is not a blocking method; it will actually start a new task that will only function when all the provided tasks complete there execution, So it is normal to see a message just a few milliseconds after program has been started, because it will not *block* at your main waiting for the tasks to finish.
From [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.continuewhenall):

> Creates a continuation task that starts when a set of specified tasks has completed.

Where the `Task.WaitAll` will *block* at the caller waiting for all of the provided Tasks to complete execution.

Comment: "upon the completion of a set of provided Tasks" that's exactly what I'm talking about, it should not create new task till all tasks from list have completed it's work. The only confusing thing here is does program waits "on that line" or program goes to next line and launches new task after completion of all tasks?

Comment: @Dan: When `ContinueWhenAll` The program will not `waits on that line` instead it will  goes to the next line and at the same time create a new task that will not function until the provided tasks finishes. but the `WaitAll` _will waiting on that line_ "block" until all provided tasks complete there execution.

Comment: Seems like this is not actually true, take a look at his link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/18/parallel-programming-task-schedulers-and-synchronization-context.aspx?PageIndex=2 and you'll find one part saying  I have already used the ContinueWhenAll method that waits for an array of tasks to finish.

Comment: There should be some other explanation to this problem

Comment: @Dan: It schedules a new task which will run after the first set of tasks finish.  It doesn't cause any waiting in the thread which calls `ContinueWhenAll`.  When that blog says it waits for an array of tasks to finish, it only means **the new task waits for the other tasks to finish**.  Sometime you should try reading [the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321473.aspx), which says "Creates a continuation Task that will be started upon the completion of a set of provided Tasks.", instead of relying on blogs.

Comment: yep, after a bit of testing with ContinueWith instead of ContinueWhenAll I realized you are both right, Sry